# How to use rxjs buffer with takeWhile

Tags: rxjs, buffer

I am working on webrtc. The application sends icecandidates to backend firestore server.
The problem is the call to signaling server is made multiple times as onicecandidate is triggered multiple time. I want collect all the icecandidates and make a single call to signaling server.
The idea is to buffer all the events untill iceGathering is finished. This below attempt does not work

```
this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
const source: Observable<any> =  fromEvent(this.pc, 'icecandidate');
const takeWhile$ = source
        .pipe(
            takeWhile(val=> val.currentTarget.iceGatheringState === 'gathering'
    ))
const buff = source.pipe(buffer(takeWhile$));
    buff.subscribe(() => {
        // this.pc.onicecandidate = onicecandidateCallback;
    })
```

Comment: So do you want to wait until `gathering` is finished then send the last value? Also where does `onicecandidateCallback` this come from? Is the problem basically "wait until status is not gathering" then assign this callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You are almost there.

The `takeWhile$` takes values and emits them while condition is met. So in `buff`, whenever `takeWhile$` emits a value, `buff` emits a buffer of `icecandidate` events.

So you only need to emit one value in `takeWhile$`.

So what you need is `takeLast()` operator to only emit the last value.

When you put `takeLast(1)` in `takeWhile$`, it only emits last value and in `buff`, last emitted value leads to creation of buffer of `icecandidate` events.

```
this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);

const source: Observable<any> = fromEvent(this.pc, "icecandidate");

const takeWhile$ = source.pipe(
  takeWhile(val => val.currentTarget.iceGatheringState === "gathering"),
  takeLast(1)
);

const buff = source.pipe(buffer(takeWhile$));

buff.subscribe((bufferValues) => {

   // bufferValues has a buffer of icecandidate events

  // this.pc.onicecandidate = onicecandidateCallback;
});
```

You'll have access to buffer of `icecandidate` events in the subscription as `bufferValues` in above code.

**Method 2:**

You can also use `reduce` operator to achieve same scenario

```
this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);

const source: Observable<any> = fromEvent(this.pc, "icecandidate");

const takeWhile$ = source.pipe(
  takeWhile(val => val.currentTarget.iceGatheringState === "gathering"),
  reduce((acc, val) => [...acc,val], [])
);

takeWhile$.subscribe((bufferValues) => {

  // bufferValues has a buffer of icecandidate events

 // this.pc.onicecandidate = onicecandidateCallback;
})
```